# How to understand the meaning 時にいくつか in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning

「今野のケータイのデザインを決める時にいくつか入手したのですがすごくカワイイです
時に」
I don't quite understand the meaning of sentence  due 時にいくつか
As I suppose the translation maybe:  It's a few to determine Konno's mobile design, when it was obtained, but it's very cute! But it isn't right translation.
 Maybe something like this or not. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's 決める時に、いくつか. I.e. `I got a few, when we decided on the design`.